# Accessing Google maps variable through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How I can load the Google maps like this:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2.x&key=ABQIAAAAAXN1Nhid00zgr5mrYEM7MhQE7kuAsiuX3WD62vgNgdNYG4wQzhQs7fQD8XzGkuXLIejRfouX3li8xg&async=2&callback=loadMap");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}
function loadMap(){
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("google_map"));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  loadMap();
  //How I can access the map variable here ?
});
```

And have access to the map variable via jQuery ?

I get an undefined error, because in the time when I try to access the map variable it is not defined yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't this way. `map` is declared locally to `loadMap` and you can't access it outside of that function. Moreover, you have to execute `loadScript` first. BTW, don't use `setAttribute` to set `src` and `type`.

Use a variable declared in the outer scope (preferably not the global scope), instead, like

```
<script>
    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2.x&key=ABQIAAAAAXN1Nhid00zgr5mrYEM7MhQ
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
    }

    loadScript();
</script>
<!-- close script element here to update DOM -->
<script>
    var map;  // declared outside loadMap

    function loadMap(){
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("google_map"));
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      loadMap();
      // Now map is available here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: With your first and last line I get an error about undefined loadMap() error, but when I comment out the first and last line, it works perfectly

Comment: @astropanic: Yeah, that was because the `documentReady` function was executed after the self-executing anonymous function ended. Now you pollute the global scope a bit more, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Change the scope of `map` variable ,say declare it outside `loadMap()` function
modify  `loadMap()` function to,

```
     var map;
     function loadMap(){
            loadScript() ;
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("google_map"));
        }
```